# Restrict FilePathField to only existing files

Tags: django

FilePathField is described in [Django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield) as:

> A CharField whose choices are limited to the filenames in a certain directory on the filesystem.

Then I assume it checks if the existence of the file. But actually it doesn't:

```
class Unit(models.Model):
     path = FilePathField(path="/home/jason/")
```

In IPython shell:

> > unit = Unit(path="non_exist_file_name")
> >     unit.save()

No exception raised. So I have to check `os.path.isfile` myself or I am not using FilePathField correctly for my need (restrict only to existing files when creating a Unit)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the validation for the `FilePathField` is not run if you don't go trough a `Form`. Try to [call `unit.clean_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) before saving.